# In Trusted Web Activity the address bar not hiding

Tags: android, url, google-play, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

After following the [Using Trusted Web Activities](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa) page about TWA's and hiding the URL bar I have followed all the instructions to hide the URL bar, but surprisingly it's not hidden.

How can I solve this?

This is my assetlinks.json file :

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "org.foodeye.mobile",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["BA:D3:3B:41:7C:1E:7B:DC:0F:FE:70:EB:33:5D:F1:A0:40:3B:09:73:A0:5D:42:80:45:DA:CB:DA:0F:9D:5A:D3"]
  }
}]
```

And this is assetlinks.json url : https://foodeye.org/.well-known/assetlinks.json

This is the manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.foodeye.mobile">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="asset_statements"
        android:value="@string/asset_statements" />

    <activity android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity"
        android:label="${launcherName}">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
            android:value="${defaultUrl}" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="${hostName}"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is build.gradle of app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.foodeye.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                hostName: "app.foodeye.org",
                defaultUrl: "https://app.foodeye.org",
                launcherName: "Food Eye",
                assetStatements: '[{ "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"], ' +
                        '"target": {"namespace": "web", "site": "https://app.foodeye.org"}}]'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.GoogleChrome.custom-tabs-client:customtabs:d08e93fce3'

}
```

This is strings.xml :

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Food Eye</string>
<string name="asset_statements">
    [{
        \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],
        \"target\": {
            \"namespace\": \"web\",
            \"site\": \"https://app.foodeye.org\"}
    }]
</string>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I access  assetlinks.json  content from the browser, I get the content below rendered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8mn5.png. It does seem to return the correct JSON using curl or using fetch in the browser, but I wonder if it may be returning the wrong content when the browsers tries to run the verification.

Comment: I was using browsable API generated by Django REST Framework. At this moment I've converted it to natural JSON format. Still, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the URL you are opening in the TWA is `https://app.foodeye.org`, but the assetlinks is hosted on `https://foodeye.org/.well-known/assetlinks.json`, which is a different origin.

You need to host the a assetlinks file on the same origin as the URL you are opening in the TWA. `https://app.foodeye.org/.well-known/assetlinks.json`